UnrealEngine is not rendering to the texture that I am creating on the device
To give you a brief . We are trying to hook on to the UnrealEngine render pipeline and fetch a frame and supply to our upstream clients . We are not using OpenXR as we have some customisation to make . We have derived a class from the HeadMountedDisplay and have implemented the functions required . I am getting all the callbacks from the UE pipeline . However on the viewport I see a black screen , which essentiallly means that UE is not rendering the texture to the frame .
Heres a brief of the texture creation code
ID3D12Device* pID3D12Device = GetID3D12DynamicRHI()->RHIGetDevice(0);
HRESULT hr = pID3D12Device->CreateCommittedResource(
    &heapProps,
    D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
    &textureDesc,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,//D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET
    &clearValue, //nullptr,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pTexture));

if (FAILED(hr) || S_FALSE == hr)
{
    // Handle the error (e.g., log it or throw an exception)
    pTexture = nullptr;
    return FXRSwapChainPtr();
}
xtureChain.Add(static_cast<FTextureRHIRef>((DynamicRHI->RHICreateTexture2DFromResource(EPixelFormat::PF_B8G8R8A8,
        CreateFlags, ClearValueBinding, pTexture))));
return  CreateXRSwapChain<FStreamXRSwapchain>(MoveTemp(TextureChain), (FTextureRHIRef&)TextureChain[0], Swapchain);

What do u think I should check ?
